# How to fix auto margin between two divs?

Tags: css, html

There is a gap between #Content-header and #sub-header which i want to fix. Here is the Css code. I want to remove the vertical margin between the two divs. The html code can be checked out at JSfiddle link provided.

CSS:

```
#content{
    float: right;
    width: 799px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 14px;font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#content-header{
    background-image: url("../images/content-header.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#content-header ul{
    padding: 10px 0 15px 30px;    
}
#content-header ul li{
    background-image: url("../images/filter-back.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
#sub-header ul{ padding-left: 0;}
#sub-header ul li{
    /*background-image: url("../images/sub-header.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;*/
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KruU5/)**

**[CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/viaec8lx)**

Comment: where is your HTML code???

Comment: Can you post html code of this part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce margin in any area use margin property and !important

```
 #content-header{
     margin: 0 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a JsFiddle example, we can make a better assessment of the issue, but if you try and give both the #content-header and the #sub-header a margin:0; then you can reset the default margin values from the user agent.

```
#content-header,
#sub-header {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}
```

It is good practice to begin your HTML/CSS pages with a css reset file, which takes all of the main html elements and resets their margin and padding to 0 (along with other attributes). That way you won't have unexpected margins and padding that show up and you can have ultimate control across browsers of your styles.

A good set css resets that I like to use is from: http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clear the two containers, as you are using floats.

Try adding `clear: both; overflow: hidden;` to #content-header element.

Also, you should wrap `<span class="switch"...</span>` with `<li></li>` tags.